# Solutions for a matrix equation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I have a equation $X^2 = \begin{bmatrix}9 & 1\\ 0 & 9 \end{bmatrix}$.  The textbook says that the Jordan matrix of $X$ can be $\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 0 & 3\end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix} -3 & 1 \\ 0 & -3\end{bmatrix}$. Therefore, this equation has 2 non-similar solutions.

My question is that why $\begin{bmatrix} -3 & 1 \\ 0 & 3\end{bmatrix}$ can not be the Jordan matrix of $X$?

Comment: If the eigenvalues are distinct then $X$ would be diagonalisable and the Jordan form would be diagonal.

Comment: @copper.hat Could you please tell more? I mean that $\begin{bmatrix} -3 & 1\\ 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$ composes of two Jordan blocks related to two distinct eigenvalues -3 and 3.

Comment: The Jordan blocks have a very specific form (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_matrix). If there is a one in the upper right, then the diagonals must be the same.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ had distinct eigenvalues (which must be $\pm 3$ in this case), then there would be a matrix of eigenvectors such that
$V^{-1} X V = \operatorname{diag}(3,-3)$. Then
$X^2 = V \operatorname{diag}(3,-3) V^{-1} V \operatorname{diag}(3,-3) V^{-1} = 9I$. Hence $X$ cannot have distinct eigenvectors.